# Refer to the last letter of a string that's in an arraylist

Tags: java

I have to store some strings into an `ArrayList` but I'm not too familiar on how to refer to the indexing of the values in an `ArrayList`. I know that I can use something like:

```
String value = mylist.get(1);
```

to get refer to the second item in the list. What I'm trying to do is refer to the last letter of the item.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
alist.add("bobb");
alist.add("Hamm");
alist.add("odffe");
```

Now, what I'm trying get is the index of the letter `"e"` from `"odffe"`. Is this something that's possible with ArrayLists? I've tried to do somethings but I think I'm treating it as a normal array and not an `ArrayList`.

I can't use `charAt()` because it says it wants char but I have Java.lang.String and I don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: I think you want the last character of a string... but do you want to do this for 1 specific item? Or do you want to make a list of all the last characters?

Answer (score 1):

You should break this task into two parts:

- Find the last string in the list
- Find the last letter of that string

Each of those tasks is pretty simple - it's realizing that there *are* two tasks that I suspect was confusing you. I'd write something like:

```
// Note: this will throw an exception if the list is empty or null
String lastElement = alist.get(alist.size() - 1);

// Note: this will throw an exception if the string is empty or null
char lastCharacter = lastElement.charAt(lastElement.length() - 1);
```

Comment: After I posted I found out the first step but the second step was something I didn't know I could do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The last letter of each string in the list should be coincident with the length of the string, so you may try:

```
List<Integer> indices = mylist.stream()
    .map(x -> x == null ? -1 : x.length() - 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```